# WordPress category menu jQuery/CSS hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to use dropdown menus for my blog that's running WordPress; what I want to do is have sub menus for my categories. So it should look like this: http://d.pr/i/jj0I - which is does.. but it also looks like this on page load - which is not what I want. Generally speaking if I wasn't using WordPress this would be an easy solution as I could add the following to my HTML.

**HTML menu without WordPress:**

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>
        <ul style="visibility: hidden;">
            <li>Sub menu - Link 1</li>
            <li>Sub menu - Link 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
</ul>
```

**HTML menu with WordPress**

```
<ul class="dropdown" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

What I'm wanting to do with WordPress is have the ability to use ***'style="visibility: hidden;"'*** on my sub menu. It's possible if I rewrote the wp_list_categories but I need to pass themecheck so I can't do that. So without using ***'style="visibility: hidden;"'*** on page load the sub-menu shows automatically without hovering over.

**My jQuery:**

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
jQuery("ul.dropdown li").hover(function() {
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("hover");
    jQuery('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

***If it helps you can view the dropdown menu live at: http://wpvault.com/kahlam-test/***

I'm sorry if I've left anything out, if I have I'll do my best to add it quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.dropdown .children{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't do that, I thought I already had it set. Thanks, its been a long day!

Answer (score 1):

Hide your ul on page load..

```
$(function() {
   $('ul.dropdown li > ul').hide();
   // Your Code here
});
```

Comment: This also works great, will keep this for future reference, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Menu creator screen and create the menus this way?

You can create hierarchical menus with the WP menu creator, and the html should be roughly equivalent to what you're looking for.

Comment: you'd use the [wp_nav_menu() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to display the menu in your theme